# Can I re-enter the US after I have been in Canada for 15 nights?

Tags: air-travel

I plan to enter the US and stay for 16 days and then go to Canada for 15 nights. I have to fly back to Los Angeles to get my flight to my home country. Am I able to do this?

Comment: Could you add details about your US entry, such as ESTA/VWP or visa info?

Comment: Usually this is fine, but the answer could depend on the details of your visa.

Comment: With less than 30 days in Canada there's almost no visa circumstance where this wouldn't be fine.

Comment: Single entry visa springs to mind.

Comment: @DJClayworth, with <30 days in Canada the AVR rules would allow the OP to resume the original US stay even with a no-longer-valid visa. As long as the US stay originally granted was long enough to cover the time in Canada as well there's little to go wrong.

Comment: @Dennis That sounds like it would be an answer.